# How to Query from Input Box Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have five  `<textarea>` tag with id of `text1,text2,text3,text4` and one `<textarea>`tags id `output` I wish to query based off the value of `text1,text2,text3,text4`(hereby known as `filed1, filed2, filed3, filed4`).

Example:

```
Value of P & T , Output Result= 3657,
```

Sample value:

```
 text1=S22, text2=P36,text3=R40,text4=T57,
```

Expected Output to `<textarea>` id wit `output` :

```
 Value of P & T:  3657
```

Here is the html code I have to set up the environment:

```
    <div>
      <label>Filed1<label>
      <textarea id="text1">S22</textarea>
   </label></label></div>
   <div>
      <label>Filed2:</label>
      <textarea id="text2">P36</textarea>
   </div>
   <div>
      <label>Filed3:</label>
      <textarea id="text3">R40</textarea>
   </div>
   <div>
      <label>Filed4:</label>
      <textarea id="text4">T57</textarea>
   </div>
   <br><br>
   <div>
    <label> Value of S & M:</label>
      <textarea id="output"></textarea>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get values from textbox using `.val()` method of jquery

```js
$('#output1').click(()=>{
var a=document.querySelectorAll('textarea');
var str='';
a.forEach(e=>e.value.includes('P')||e.value.includes('T')?str+=e.value.substr(1,e.value.length):false)
$('#output1').val(str);

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
      <label>Filed1<label>
      <textarea id="text1">S22</textarea>
   </label></label></div>
   <div>
      <label>Filed2:</label>
      <textarea id="text2">P36</textarea>
   </div>
   <div>
      <label>Filed3:</label>
      <textarea id="text3">R40</textarea>
   </div>
   <div>
      <label>Filed4:</label>
      <textarea id="text4">T57</textarea>
   </div>
   <br><br>
   <div>
    <label> Value of S & M:</label>
      <textarea id="output"></textarea>
      <label> Value of P & T:</label>
      <textarea id="output1"></textarea>
    </div>
```

Comment: nop, Value of P & T may random like Value of Q & R, G & T

Comment: Value of P & T may dynamically change and also change  remain four filed value

Comment: instead of click even listener call the function on change of the textarea value